# wget specify downloaded file name and directory

Tags: bash, wget

I have a file called `input.txt` with list of urls I want to download. Urls may contain query parameters at the end and I want to strip off it from output files, so the names will be pretty. In addition I have `$prefix` I want to use and create directories automatically if they don't exist.

The script I'm using:

```
cat input.txt | while read line; do
   wget -P "$prefix" -O `echo $line | sed 's/^.*\///' | sed 's/\?.*$//'` $line
done
```

`-P` option helps to specify prefix and what is more important **create directories** if they don't exist. But the file names without `-O` option will contain ugly query parameters.

`-O` option helps to specify file names. In my script I'm cutting "bad" parts of urls using `sed` ( url part before last `/` and query parameters after `?` ). The only problem is that `-O`  option **doesn't create** directories if they don't exist.

Finally `wget` **doesn't allow** to use both options at same time. Is there a solution to a problem?

Comment: something , some o/p showing problem

Comment: you can also give the filename at the end like this `done < file`

Comment: I would suggest posting some data from your `input.txt` file.

Comment: @JS웃 Almost each line is something similar to url with query access token and signiture like `https://sd1.sd2.domain/dir1/dir2/file?access_token=XXX&sign=YYY`. And instead of long name with query I want to have just `file` name

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
while read line; do
    dest=${line%%\?*}
    dest=${dest##*/}
    mkdir -p "$prefix"
    wget -O "$prefix/$dest" "$line"
done <input.txt
```

The Bash variable manipulations are basically equivalent to your `sed` script, only more efficient (and perhaps somewhat more robust) as no external process is involved.

Note also the double quotes around the variable interpolation. Any variable containing a file name -- and more generally, any variable interpolation at all, most of the time -- needs to be in double quotes.